# How to perform divide operation in jolt using 'modify-overwrite-beta'

Tags: jolt

Input,

```
 {"scores": [  4,2,8,7,5  ] }
```

Output,

```
 {"FirstElement": 2 } //This is generated by dividing the first element of the array by 2.
```

Spec,

```
 [{
 "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
 "spec": {
    "Avg": "=divide(=firstElement(@(1,scores)),2)"
  }
}]
```

From the above Spec,I am trying to divide the first element of the list by 2 but the output I get is same as the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't nest "functions" with modify.   Have to break it up into two steps.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "firstElement": "=firstElement(@(1,scores))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Avg": "=divide(@(1,firstElement),2)"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Got it.Thanks Milo.

Comment: ,need some help from you,Can you please suggest me some documentations related to JOLT.